# $f(x_1,x_2)= \int_0^{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2}} e^{-(w^2/({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2))}$dw

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

consider function $f(x_1,x_2)= \int_0^{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2}} e^{-(w^2/({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2))}$dw with property that $f(0,0)=0$. Then function $f(x_1,x_2)$is

1. homogeneous of degree $-1$
2. homogeneous of degree $\frac{1}{2}$
3. homogeneous of degree $1$
4. none

my doubt: problem here is that integration of $ e^{w^2}  $  is required here I guess. which I don't know

Comment: You've done exactly what you did in your last question.. As Martigan said previously, you need to tell us what you have done, what your approach is etc so we can help you. We _are not_ here to do your work for you.

Comment: Then make an edit to your post and explain what you have done, where you got confused, what confused you etc.